# VBA Excel Copy and Paste a table into a new Workbook and choice which Columns i want to copy

Tags: vba, excel

I want to copy a table into a new Workbook while choosing which range I want to copy and knowing that the first Columns ("A") is automatically copied. (rows are not a problem, all of them have to be copied)
For example, i have a table composed of 28 rows and 10 columns. Added to A1:A28 (first columns, all rows),i want just to copy the column 5 and 8 with all its rows.
That's what i have until now but it doesn't work.

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  Dim newWB As Workbook, currentWB As Workbook
  Dim newS As Worksheet, currentS As Worksheet
  Dim CurrCols As Variant
  Dim rng As rang
  'Copy the data you need
    Set currentWB = ThisWorkbook
    Set currentS = currentWB.Sheets("Feuil1")
    'select which columns you want to copy
    CurrCols = InputBox("Select which column you want to copy from        table (up to 10)")
    If Not IsNumeric(CurrCols) Then
    MsgBox "Please select a valid Numeric value !", vbCritical
    End
    Else
    CurrCols = CLng(CurrCols)
    End If
    'Set rng = currentWB.currentS.Range(Cells(1, A), Cells(27, CurrCols)).Select
    currentS.Range("A1:A27").Select
    Selection.copy
    Set rng = currentWB.currentS.Range(Cells(1, CurrCols), Cells(28, CurrCols)).Select
    rng.copy
    'Create a new file that will receive the data
    Set newWB = Workbooks.Add
    With newWB
    Set newS = newWB.Sheets("Feuil1")
    newS.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues,    Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
End With
End Sub
```

Can you help please solving it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: what does _"copy the column 5 and 8 with all its rows"_ actually mean? post examples of input and output data

Comment: For example i have as Input a table composed of 28 lines and columns from A until G. As Output i would like to get a table of 28 lines and just the columns A, C and F from my Input (so it's composed of three columns taken from my input)

Comment: where in your code do I get 1) the "Input" table 2) columns to be selected ?

Comment: In currentWB.currentS i have already my table from it i will select my columns. Just after the comment: 'select which columns you want to copy; I start selecting the columns, CurrCols is which columns i want to copy 
Set rng = currentWB.currentS.Range(Cells(1, CurrCols), Cells(28, CurrCols)).Select
    rng.copy
is to copy this column and paste it but it doesn't work!! 

currentS.Range("A1:A27").Select
    Selection.copy
is just to copy the first columns with all the lines because i always need it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't copy a non-continuous range but you can load the data into an array and write it once to the new workbook.

[image]

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim arData
    Dim MyColumns As Range, Column As Range
    Dim x As Long, y As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    Set MyColumns = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Hold down [Ctrl] and click the columns to copy", Title:="Copy Columns to new Workbook", Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If MyColumns Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Set MyColumns = Union(Columns("A"), MyColumns.EntireColumn)

    Set MyColumns = Intersect(MyColumns, ActiveSheet.UsedRange)

    ReDim arData(1 To MyColumns.Rows.Count, 1 To 1)

    For Each Column In MyColumns.Columns
        y = y + 1
        If y > 1 Then ReDim Preserve arData(1 To MyColumns.Rows.Count, 1 To y)
        For x = 1 To Column.Rows.Count
            arData(x, y) = Column.Rows(x)
        Next
    Next

    With Workbooks.Add().Worksheets(1)
        .Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arData, 1), UBound(arData, 2)) = arData
        .Columns.AutoFit
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

try this (commented) code

```
Option Explicit

Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim newSht As Worksheet
    Dim currCols As String
    Dim area As Range
    Dim iArea As Long

    Set newSht = Workbooks.add.Worksheets("Feuil1") '<--| add a new workbook and set its "Feuil1" worksheet as 'newSht'
    currCols = Replace(Application.InputBox("Select which column you want to copy from table (up to 10)", "Copy Columns", "A,B,F", , , , , 2), " ", "") '<--| get columns list

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Feuil1") '<--| reference worksheet "Feuil1" in the workbook this macro resides in
        For Each area In Intersect(.Range(ColumnsAddress(currCols)), .Range("A1:G28")).Areas ' loop through referenced worksheet areas of the range obtained by crossing its listed columns with its range "A1:G28"
            With area '<--| reference current area
                newSht.Range("A1").Offset(, iArea).Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).value = .value '<--| copy its values in 'newSht' current column offset from "A1" cell
                iArea = iArea + .Columns.Count '<--| update current column offset from 'newSht' worksheet "A1" cell
            End With
        Next area
    End With
End Sub

Function ColumnsAddress(strng As String) As String
    Dim elem As Variant

    For Each elem In Split(strng, ",")
        ColumnsAddress = ColumnsAddress & elem & ":" & elem & ","
    Next
    ColumnsAddress = Left(ColumnsAddress, Len(ColumnsAddress) - 1)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can copy all column to a temp sheet and then write some code to delete the useless column. finally paste the table to your expected area.

Comment: there is no solution to just select the columns that i want to be copied and make like an Union to them and than Paste ?

Comment: If you union them. say you want to copy column 5 and 8. The result you pasted may be on column 5 and 6 because the pasted area must be consecutive.

Comment: Please upvote my answer if you think it is ok. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry i was in travel and haven't access to internet! i just get it now!! i'll try it and give you a feedback

Comment: thanks Chan it works perfectly! i just want to keep the same format and c olors of each columns and rows!